# How to click export to excel in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, export-to-excel

I have 3 lists in SharePoint. But in 2 lists different button "Export to Excel" can be click. but in 1 list, it cannot be click.

[image]

Comment: From your description, export to excel is greyed out in one list. What permission do you have on that issued list? You can switch to other user account who have full control permission to check whether it worked. What is the list type of that issued list?

Comment: can you please check your permission for that specific list.

Comment: from third list which exists, I am set the same permission. I am set contribute

Comment: from third list which exists, I am set the same permission. I am set contribute

Comment: What is the list type of that third list?

Comment: Every other controls are disabled in the above picture. So can you please try with "Full Control" permission.

Comment: yes, I am set permission contribute in the third list

Comment: I mean is it custom list, or calendar list, or survey list and so on...?

Comment: oh sorry. yes, custom list

Comment: Whether other users can use export to excel in third list.

Comment: Hi Guys, sorry now can. I do sign out then re-sign in. and the export to excel button can be clicked. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try other approaches to export list items for that specific list.

**URL Approach:**

**Template URL:**

```
SITEURL/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={YOUR LIST ID}&View={YOUR VIEW ID}&CacheControl=1
```

**Example URL:**

```
http://sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy& List={94234BEC-FAE1-4B4C-80E8-2AE5F9B419CB}View={A3081327-C448-47E4-A076-CE0A1BCED059}&CacheControl=1
```

Answer (score 0):

To make solutions easier for more people to discover, I'll make a summary of this case.

Sign out then re-sign in solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

There are many possibilities of being **"Export to Excel"** grayed out.

**Possibles Causes:**

There are multiple causes for this, including:

- Excel is not installed
- Incompatible version of Excel
- You are not in a List View
- Your Act! user permissions do not allow the option
- User Account Control (UAC) settings are blocking the integration
  (windows Vista and later only)

**Possible Solution:**

**Excel is not installed**

This can occur if you do not have Excel installed on the computer where you are trying to export data to Excel. If you wish to export data from Act! to Excel, you must do so from a computer which has both Act! and Excel installed on it.

**Note**: Microsoft Office programs must be installed before Act! is installed in order to function properly with Act!. If you decide to install Excel to your computer after you have already installed Act!, it will be necessary for you to uninstall and reinstall Act!. For information on uninstalling and installing Act!

**You are not using a compatible version of Excel**

In order for the Export to Excel option to work, you must be using a version of Excel from a compatible version of Microsoft Office. For information on compatible versions of Excel by version of Act!

**You are not in a list view**

1. Navigate to the List views:

It could be a "view" issue - i.e. if you are in "Structure" view it will not save as excel - get them to click "View Results" and try again if this is indeed the problem.

2. Verify whether the Export to Excel option is grayed out. If it is, proceed to the next section

**If nothing works check the permission of the user**

**Reference URLs:**

https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024250474-Export-to-Excel-option-is-grayed-out-in-Act-

http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=898979

**Using REST API coding "Export to Excel"**

```
/sites/dev01/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.7.1.min.js



function getViewAsHtml(viewId, viewTitle)
 {

var headers = {
 Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
 };

var call = jQuery.ajax({
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
 + "/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Views('"+viewId+"')/renderAsHtml()",
 type: "GET",
 data: "json",
 headers: headers
 });

call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
 $('#viewTitle').html("
"+viewTitle +"
");
 $('#printView').html(data.d.RenderAsHtml);
 window.location=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Using=_layouts/15/query.iqy&List=%7B00361C78%2D4158%2D4A9B%2DA12D%2D8C55DE4E9079%7D&View=%7B"+viewId +"%7D&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fdev01%2FLists%2FTestList&CacheControl=1";
 });

call.fail(failHandler);

function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
 var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
 alert("Call failed. Error : " + message);
 }
 }

function createViews()
 {

var headers = {
 Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
 };

var viewName = "By Status" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
 var call = jQuery.ajax({
 url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
 + "/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Views",
 type: "POST",
 data: JSON.stringify({
 "__metadata": { type: "SP.View" },
 Title: viewName,
 'PersonalView': false,
 'ViewQuery':'',
 'RowLimit': 3
 }),
 headers: headers
 });

call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
 getViewAsHtml(data.d.Id, data.d.Title);
 });

call.fail(failHandler);

function failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
 var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
 alert("Call failed. Error : " + message);
 }
 }

$(document).ready(function()
 {
 //getViewAsHtml();
 });

 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
```

**Reference URL:**

https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/sharepoint-2013-export-to-excel-using-rest-api/